# While loading a document using XMLHttpRequest what is the size of offset which it loads

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Suppose that I am loading a document called `data.text` with 12 Megabyte size, I want to know that in how many times my data is loaded and how much size of data is loaded each time, by using `XMLHttpRequest` Object.
and is the size of loading data each time different between various browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by `in how many times`? The request will load the whole file at once if you don't specify a byte range.

Comment: The amount of data will be browser dependent and varies for all sorts of reasons. For general progress monitoring and size transferred during the time XHR is active you can use this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Comment: @tkausl when we use `onprogress` event when will notice that it loads the data in multiple time not at once

Comment: Well but this has nothing to do with XMLHttpRequest, this is just how TCP works.

Comment: @RandyCasburn So you mean that the size of data which the browser loads are different and there is no fixed offset each time that it loads